# What graph is this?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

For my game I am trying to implement a continues world by interconnecting the nodes like below

I beg your pardon for my bad drawings

[image]

I don't know how to explain it but its NOT DENSE GRAPH

It is representation of 3x3 nodes
Where every node is connected to adjacent node vertically or diagonally (edges in turquoise color)

Ex:

1-2, 1-4
2-1,2-3,2-5
5-2, 5-6, 5-4, 5-8

Now there are some edges (colored in blue and purple)

1-7, 1-3
4-6
2-8

I need edges like this for creating endless/continues world for my game

My world is actually lot bigger than this but I made 3x3 for the sake of drawing.

Is there any name for this type of graph?

Comment: Every node isn't connected to adjacent node in the graph you shown. Torodial graph is the closes to what your describing.

Comment: Also, you should post on gamedev stackexchange.

Comment: Isn't this a cartesian product of cycles?

Comment: It's a torodial graph. A graph that can be embedded into a torus. A torus is a cartesian product of cycles.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know about this graph? What do you need to do with it?

Comment: its like a globe. world map in a plane

Comment: and I want to know name of the graph for documenting and implement standard algorithm if there is any

Comment: This graph isn't like a globe.  It's like the surface of a donut.

Answer (score 2):

@Johannes Kloos is right. The graph in the picture is just the cartesian product of $C_3$ with itself. I think in general you are interested in the cartesian product of $C_k$ and $C_l$.

Answer (score 2):

> "Where every node is connected to adjacent node vertically or diagonally"

Judging from the picture, it should say horizontally instead of diagonally.  And if the vertices are connected to every vertex vertically and horizontally, fidbc's answer is correct for the $3 \times 3$ case, but not in general.

If the above is correct, this graph is known as the $3 \times 3$ [rook's graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph).  Generalising this to the $k \times n$ case, it is the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of $K_k$ and $K_n$, and the [line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of the complete bipartite graph $K_{k,n}$.

If $n \geq k$, then the number of $n$-colourings of of the $k \times n$ rook's graph is the number of [Latin rectangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) of order $n$.  In particular, the number of $n$-colourings of of the $n \times n$ rook's graph is the number of [Latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) of order $n$.  Further, the [chromatic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) of this graph counts a generalisation of Latin rectangles.

I discuss this graph in my survey paper [The Many Formulae for the Number of Latin Rectangles](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1a1).